# Problem with Relational Database in MVC Linq to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I was hoping someone could tell me what is wrong here. I have three tables, LU_LOC_Suburb, Listings, ListingMessages.

---

**Listings has the following columns**

ID

SuburbID (Coming from LU_LOC_Suburb)

more...

---

**ListingMessages has the following columns**

ID

ListingID (Coming from Listings)

more...

---

I'm trying to create a Messages page where I first get all the Message for a User;

```
IQueryable<ListingMessage> Messages = from x in DBEntities.ListingMessageSet.Include("Listings")
                                      where x.Listings.Users.ID == UserID
                                      select x;
```

I then send this to a View, lets call it **Messages for User.**

I also limit the messages by listing by taking all the messages for a user and then only selecting the ones that are related to a particular listing;

```
Messages = from x in Messages
           where x.Listings.ID == ListingID
           select x;
```

I then send this to a View, lets call it **Messages for Listing.**

In my View Pages, I want to write the suburb name to screen which I can do by;

```
<%= Html.Encode(item.Listings.LU_LOC_Suburb.Name) %>
```

Now here's the problem...

This gives the error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object - when I DON'T limit the Messages by Listing (in the **Messages for User** View). I do not get this error when I limit the messages by listing.

I dont understand why this is happening. I know it's something simple and am hoping you guys can help me resolve this?

Thanks in advance,

Sheefy

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you haven't "Included" the "listings" in the Message query?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Everything stems from the initial query where Listings is included. I am able to read the different listings - the problem is when I don't limit the messages by a particular listing, I cannot read the LU_LOC_Suburb table (this table is referenced in the Listings table).

So, the first query (by user) doesn't allow me to read the LU_LOC_Suburb Column referenced in the Listings table, but the second query (where I take the results from the frst and further limit them by ListngID) allows me to read the LU_LOC_Suburb Column referenced in the Listings table.

Answer (score 0):

As you may or may not know, `IQueryable` is a 'lazy' representation of the actual query. It is not executed until enumerated over. From your code sample, it seems like you're sending the `IQueryable` directly to your view. Not sure if that is 'wrong' but I always make sure the query is actually executed in the controller. You can do this by adding a ToList() to the statement, when adding it to your ViewModel (or ViewData).

I'm not saying that this will solve your problem, but it *will* make debugging much easier.

Comment: I had a go at that but no luck. It seems that the Listings results are filling when it's called to the view, however, all the tables related to the Listings table are null.